# Can't connect to container at Docker-compose (Spring Cloud Config Server)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud

So I have two Docker images (Spring Boot apps) and I'm trying to connect them in docker-compose.yml, but one doesn't see the other :(

Here's what I get: Fetching config from server at : http://server_config:8888 (and finally timeout)

**EDIT:** so it took me three days to figure out that docker containers can't contain the '_' character and after renaming my server_config to serverconfig everything works just fine :)

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  server_config:
    container_name: server_config
    image: server:latest
    environment:
            SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{"eureka": {"client": {"serviceUrl": {"defaultZone": "http://discUser:discPassword@server_discovery:8083/eureka/"}}}}' 
    ports:
      - 8888:8888

  server_discovery:
    container_name: server_discovery
    image: discovery:latest
    environment:
            SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{"spring": {"cloud": {"config": {"uri": "http://server_config:8888"}}}}'
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    links:
      - server_config
    depends_on:
      - server_config
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://server_config:8888/login"]
```

*server_config's application.properties*

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=configserver
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/k-wasilewski/SpringCloud_server_config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.security.user.name=configUser
spring.security.user.password=configPassword
spring.security.user.role=SYSTEM

eureka.client.region=default
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds=5
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discUser:discPassword@localhost:8083/eureka/
```

*server_discovery's bootstrap.properties*

```
spring.application.name=discovery
spring.cloud.config.name=discovery
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.username=configUser
spring.cloud.config.password=configPassword

spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
spring.cloud.config.retry.initial-interval=1500
spring.cloud.config.retry.multiplier=1.5
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-attempts=10000
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-interval=1000
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Because it isn't running at localhost (i.e. in the same docker container). Instead of localhost, use the name of the container you want to connect to. The same obviously applies to your eureka URL as well.

Comment: Sorry, I have already changed it in docker-compose and now it's:  Fetching config from server at http://server_config:8888

Comment: It needs to be different in the bootstrap.properties else it won't have any effect. Also if that is your actual yaml config the indentation is wrong.

Comment: I've removed the ENV vars and changed the hostname in bootstrap.properties - didn't work...

Comment: I've noticed that my server_config at docker-compose is available at localhost:8888, but the server_discovery still doesn't see it from neither at localhost nor at server_config host...

Comment: Try adding a `Network:` section to both, and making sure they're both in the same network.

Comment: Already tried it, doesn't work either (aren't all docker-compose services already in a default network?)...

Comment: It will be available at `localhost` from your own machine **NOT** from the inside of the docker container. Also does your config server actually start, as that tries to connect to eureka (according to your config) also on local host (which probably needs to point to something else as well). Looks like you have a chicken/egg problem. The config server needs the eureka service to be up and vice versa...

Comment: I know about that circularity, but then why does it work locally? I assumed that configserver is up even without conn to eureka, then eureka starts and fetches its config, finally configserver registers at eureka.. Can I deploy it like that on Docker??